# How to avoid having views "marked inoperative"?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

How can I modify tables/views that impact other views without having those dependent views "marked inoperative"?

We're running DB2 9.5 LUW. I've read Leons Petrazickis' blog post *[Find a list of views marked inoperative](http://lpetr.org/blog/archives/find-a-list-of-views-marked-inoperative)* where he says,

> There are also ways to avoid it using transactions, CREATE OR REPLACE statements, and other measures.

Since we can't take advantage of the new features in 9.7 I need someone to elaborate on these other ways that Leons mentions. An example that runs in IBM Data Studio would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "CREATE OR REPLACE" functionality was added in DB2 9.7.  Prior to this, the only way to avoid marking views inoperative is to  drop the views before making the changes to the objects underneath the views, and recreate the views after.

Or, avoid making changes to the views' dependent objects.  :-)

Comment: Any idea what Leons might be referring to when he suggests using transactions?

Comment: He is referring to a method to prevent users from seeing the SQL0575N error.  This does not prevent DB2 from marking an object invalid.  When making the DDL changes within a single transaction, other queries will just block on locks in the system catalog until the DDL transaction commits.